# Need help in JavaScript to change and stop background video

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my site I have a video in background. Now I want to add two buttons, One will stop the video/start the video and one will stop the video and replace it with a image. 
This is my site - [site link](http://minidots.cf)

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please check that again :)

Comment: How about hide and plause the video em show the image? The image should be related to the video current frame?

Comment: Yah, It's also can be @Prusse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to create the two buttons and style them as desired but here is the code you'll need to start/stop the video:

```
// assuming we're inside of your click listener callback
var video = document.querySelector('video');
if (video.playing) {
    video.pause() // will bring the video to a halt
    video.currentTime = 0; // brings it back to the beginning 
} else {
    video.play();
}
```

here is the code you'll need to replace the video with an image:

```
// assuming we're inside of your click listener callback
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var newImage = document.createElement('img');
newImage.src = 'source-of-your-image.jpg';
video.parentNode.insertBefore(newImage, video); // inserts img into DOM
video.parentNode.removeChild(video); // removes the video
```

Comment: It's working, but If I want to play the video again where it was paused after replacing with the image, then what should I do?

Comment: just remove the line: `video.currentTime = 0;`

Comment: I have already removed that line, but after showing image, I want to play the video again from where it was stopped. how can I do that?

Comment: you'll have to set a top-scoped variable that will store where the video was... `var videoPosition;` and where we're doing the pausing (`video.pause()`) do `videoPosition = video.currentTime;` and when you want to go play the video again from where it was, just set the videos current time: `video.currentTime = videoPosition;`

Comment: From your code, when I am clicking the bbutton to replace the image its deleting video property. now I want that again when I will click the button it will play the video. Please help me to do that.

Comment: when the image is shown and you want to render the video...
create the video element:
`var video = document.createElement('video');`
---------
`video.setAttribute('autoplay', '')`
---------
`image.parentNode.insertBefore(video, image);`
---------
`image.parentNode.removeChild(image);`

Answer (score 0):

You need some code like this to get the element by ID and for play/pause

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
}
```

And the HTML could be a[href]:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playVid()">Play</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pauseVid()">Pause</a>
```

To display the image you can use the [poster](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster) attribute for video html5 tag. The image will display until the video is loaded and play is clicked and you can display it by reloading the video:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
function displayPoster() {
    vid.load();
}
```